# Is there any way to disable UAC prompts for just one program?

Tags: windows, windows-10, visual-studio, uac, visual-studio-2019

I have to run Visual Studio as an administrator to debug web apps running on my local IIS server, but I don't like getting a UAC prompt every time I fire it up. I don't want to disable UAC globally though, only for Visual Studio, because I trust it. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

If you run `devenv.exe` from an elevated command prompt it will open without UAC.

The other way is to make a scheduled task that runs elevated with no schedule. Then you can run the task manually to open `devenv.exe`

If your task was named "VisualStudio" you would make a shortcut that contains:

```
schtasks /run /TN "VisualStudio"
```

EXAMPLE:
https://www.thewindowsclub.com/create-elevated-shortcut-run-programs-bypass-uac

Comment: Oh, that's pretty neat! But how do I make sure the task runs only on demand? I have to pick a schedule for it to run automatically in Windows 10; there's no option to skip that step...

Comment: I gave an example of a shortcut you could make that would run a task

Comment: Shortcut target for a task inside a folder: `C:\Windows\System32\schtasks.exe /RUN /TN "MyCustomTasks\PowerShellAdmin"`